# String from Grouped Dictionary Returning nil in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array, uicollectionview

I'm trying to return a string value from a grouped dictionary in my CollectionViewController.swift file. Here is my function which creates the dictionary:

```
  var groupArray = [String: [Entity]]()
  var categoryKeys: [String]? = []

func fetchGroups() {
  var groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: categories.results, by: {$0.kind})
          [
            "book": [
              Entity,
              ].self,
            "movie": [
              Entity
              ].self,
            "song": [
              Entity
              ].self,
            "podcast": [
              Entity
              ].self   
          ]

 self.groupArray = groupedDictionary as? [String : [Entity]]

          for i in self.groupArray {
            self.categoryKeys?.append(i.key)
           }

          let encodedData = try!  JSONEncoder().encode(groupedDictionary)
          let jsonResult = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)
          print(jsonResult!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        }

      } catch let err{
        print(err)
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
```

Then for my collection view I have:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    var accessArray: [Entity] = ([])

    for i in self.groupArray{
      for t in i.value {
        self.images?.append(t.artwork!)

        accessArray.append(t)
        let group = p.value[indexPath.row]
      }
   }

    let group = accessArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel.text = group.name

    return cell
  }
```

However, cell.textLabel.text = group.name  is returning nil and I'm not sure why... (Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file)

I have a feeling that it may have something to do with not safely declaring/wrapping the groupArray.. The goal is to make the contents of the grouped dictionary accessible for the collectionview cell. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: basically your `cell`'s `textLabel` is `nil` I think

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing that now.. not sure why, but it has something to do with registering my custom collectionView Cell..